# Is it ok to serialize a List of Views?

Tags: android

I want to send a list of views inside a bundle, so the activity can be reconstructed using the values from before it get destroyed, for example when the user rotate the device, but I start getting errors on retrieving the views.. Is that okay to use that approach?

PS. I didn't post code because I think that would be unnecessary, if you guys think it would be nice to read the code, please request and I will update the question.

Comment: "Is that ok to use that approach?" -- oh, `$DEITY`, no.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have the right idea but incorrect implementation. Use onSaveInstanceState, and if you want you can put things into your Bundle. Lets take a more practical example, such as a string value.

```
private TextView mTextView;
private static final String KEY_TEXT_VALUE = "keyTextValue";

@Override 
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(KEY_TEXT_VALUE, mTextView.getText());
}
```

Whenever Android destroys and recreates your Activity for orientation change it calls onSaveInstanceState() before destroying and calls onCreate() after creating. So if you want, you can retrieve the saved information in onCreate() like this,

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main);
   if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      String savedText = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_TEXT_VALUE);
      // do something with savedText
   } 
}
```

If you have a lot of data you may consider creating some sort of cache, SQLite would be sufficient enough.

Comment: I definitely agree with this approach. Having to store the Views is not the right way to go. Also instead of `onSaveInstance()` you could also use `onPause()` and `onResume()` to store and retrieve data respectively.

Comment: Yea, nice, but I dont really wanto to have to implement it on every single activity/fragment I create, I need something more generic, that's why I was  serializing the views, but I may use a map instead and serialize the values of it, something like that may works. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Marcos your idea is not appropriate. If this is something you will commonly do, how about using my logic in a BaseActivity that you can extend out of so that you can have same code space for any other Activities that you want. You don't have to implement it on every single activity/fragment, you only have to extend the BaseActivity.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to serialize the **data** the views need to redraw themselves and restore their state if the size of your list isn't really big. You should not be serializing the views itself.

When you serialize too much data, you will know as your app will crash :)

When there is too much data, use SQL instead or just tell your activity or fragment not to destroy itself and avoid this hassle altogether.

Comment: I am serializing the views themselves, its working fine with regular views, but I tried to serialize a RecyclerView and it crashed.. :(

Comment: I know it works fine, but recyclerview is doing a fine job to draw them. You are saving a lot more by saving the views instead if of what is important to resraw them. Just keep texts, checked states, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the state of your Activity, save it into `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, this method belongs to Activity class. For example:

```
savedInstanceState.putString(USER_NAME, myEditText.getText.toString());
```

In `onCreate()` method you can retrieve your data this way:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // restore as many values from views as you need
    mUserName = savedInstanceState.getString(USER_NAME);
}
```

You may also consider using this line of code.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

This will prevent your app from reseting your data when orientation changes.

Also see this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).